# Show Child Window in Task Switcher

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, alt-tab

How can I make a modeless child dialog (instantiated using CreateDialogParam) show up in the windows task switcher (Alt-Tab strip)? Using the WS_EX_APPWINDOW window style forces the dialog to have a taskbar icon but not in the task switcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raymond Chen gives the full gory details here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863

Comment: Any chance this document still exists somewhere?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863  which I found using the wayback machine, a super resource for such things